# ¿Que problema tiene mi código?

Tags: r

Estoy interiorizándome en este lenguaje y en este caso necesito saber en este caso el día mas caluroso del mes de junio de la base de datos `airquality`.

Mi código es así pero el resultado que arroja es sin aplicar el `order`, entonces me arroja bien, un solo valor y del mes de junio, solo que no es el de la temperatura mas baja.

```
miIris= head(airquality[airquality$Month == 6 & order(airquality$Temp), ], 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un problema de lógica aquí:

```
airquality$Month == 6 & order(airquality$Temp)
```

La comparación `airquality$Month == 6` retorna un vector de lógicos, `TRUE` cuando el mes es junio, pero `order(airquality$Temp)` simplemente retorna un vector de númericos mayores a 0 (la posición de la fila una ves ordenada), que se "coercionan" a un valor lógico cuando utilizas el `&`, y cualquier número mayor a 0 será `TRUE`, por lo que esto último da lo mismo que esté o no este. Lo que en definitiva ocurre es que estás intentando aplicar dos acciones, filtro y orden al mismo tiempo, y en realidad deberían ser acciones independientes, por ejemplo:

```
tmp <- airquality[airquality$Month == 6, ] # Filtramos por mes
tmp <- tmp[order(-tmp$Temp), ]             # Ordenamos
head(tmp, 1)                               # La máxima temperatura
```

Puedes simplificar las dos operaciones en una sola línea, aunque deberías ordenar el `data.frame` completo para luego filtrar:

```
subset(airquality[order(-airquality$Temp),],
       Month == 6)[1,]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedó muy claro el concepto. ¡Saludos!